# React on click over an area as long as it was not an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large area that I need to make clickable. Imagine I have a list of items:

```
<ul class="my-area">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

The items `<li>` have a lot of stuff inside including working links or links that trigger modal windows etc. As long as someone clicks on one of the links inside, it should do whatever it is designated to do - redirect, open modal window, etc. However, if the click was not on a link but just a `<div>`, `<span>` etc, then I need to redirect to a specific location.

I've tried this:

```
$("ul.my-area li:not(a)").click(function (event) {
    location.href='SOME_LOCATION';
});
```

However, it's not working. I considered using `.stopPropagation()` as well but then the modal windows stop working so that's not an option. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a demo? I am wondering if $(selector).on("click", function (){}) may work instead?

Answer (score 2):

**edited:** There is two posible solutions:
**First solution:**`event.stopPropagation()` **`*(not an option for this specific question because of modals)*`**- this would look like:

```
$("ul.my-area li").on('click',function (event) {           
//location.href='SOME_LOCATION';
});

$("ul.my-area li a").on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

**Second solution:** Since you have nested `DIV, IMG...` inside the `anchors`, here it is checking if `clicked element` is not an `anchor` or if it don't have any `ancestor anchor`, and inside you can change **`location.href/do some action`**:

```
$("ul.my-area li ").on('click', function(event) {

      if (!((event.target.tagName == "A") || $(event.target).closest('a').length)) {
        console.log("This is not an anchor");
        //location.href='SOME_LOCATION';
      }
      else{ //it's an anchor }
    });
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
$("ul.my-area li ").on('click', function(event) {

  if (!((event.target.tagName == "A") || $(event.target).closest('a').length)) {
    console.log("This is not an anchor");
    //location.href='SOME_LOCATION';
  }
  else{ //it's an anchor }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="my-area">
  <li>
    <p>This is Paragraf <a href="#">This is Anchor</a>
    </p>
    <div>This is DIV</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>This is another Paragraf</p>
    <a href="#">
      <div>This Div inside Anchor<span> This is span inside div inside the anchor</span>
      </div>
      <img src="" alt="Image part of the anchor">
    </a>
    <p>Some paragraf</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm getting all kinds of tags like DIV, IMG, etc when I click on links but never an A tag...

Comment: do you have nested `divs`, or `imgs` inside anchors?

Comment: Yes, inside and outside of them, it's a complete mess. However, some of the nested stuff there does not have links in it at all, some of the rest does...